# Why does mysqli_num_rows always return 0?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to check the input of the user after he hits the submit button if the word exist in the database.

Hence, I have this code. However, it always says Data does not exist in which it finds the condition false.

What is wrong with my code below?

```
$input_word = trim($_POST["word"]);
$data_check = "SELECT * FROM word_collections WHERE single_word = '$input_word'";
$a = mysqli_query($data_check);
if (mysqli_num_rows($a) == 1)
{
    echo "Data exist.";
}
else
{
    echo "Data DOES NOT exist";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't return more than 1? More importantly, you are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: i've read an article that mysqli_num_rows will only return either 1 or 0 @MagnusEriksson

Comment: No..  it returns the number of rows returned in the query. "num_rows" = "number of rows". If you have questions about a php-function, you should always start at the soure: [the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: not entirely true. There could be more than one record. Try `>0`, and if that fails, then your query may have failed and you need to check for errors.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i tried using > 0 and it is still saying Data does not exist, in which i already have it in my database

Comment: I posted an answer below @KatieSerenVera

Comment: Just as a side note you could add `LIMIT 1` to the database query so that you can keep it as `== 1` and also so that it speeds up your query as it'll stop as soon as it's found a matching result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query failed because you didn't pass db connection to:

```
$a = mysqli_query($data_check);
```

The variable for the connection is unknown, so you need to base yourself on:

```
$a = mysqli_query($connection, $data_check);
```

and you may have to use `>0` instead of `==1` for your `num_rows()` as there could be more than one record.

Your code is also open to an sql injection; use a prepared statement.

Use PHP's [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and `mysqli_error($connection)` on the query.

Also make sure that your connection is in fact `mysqli_` and not another api.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input_word = trim($_POST["word"]);
    $data_check = "SELECT * FROM word_collections WHERE single_word = '$input_word'";
                        $con = mysqli_connect("host",'id','pass','dbname'); // add this connection
                        $a = mysqli_query($con,$data_check);
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($a) == 1)
                        {
                            echo "Data exist.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "Data DOES NOT exist";
                        }
```

You need to put your connection in mysqli_query parameter 1. You may refer tutorial from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp) .

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this.

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'username';
$dbuser = 'password';
$dbpass = 'dbname';
$dbConn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$query = "SELECT * FROM word_collections WHERE single_word = '$input_word'";

$result = $dbConn->query($query);
if($result->num_rows == 1){
    echo "have some records";
}else{
    echo "No records";
}
```